# Web API and Composed media types

Tags: asp.net-web-api, media-type

Is there any support for handling composed media types?
Example:

```
Content-Type: application/contact+xml
Content-Type: application/document+json
```

I know there is the possibility of using a **mediatypeformatter**/***mediatypemapping***, but is there something else?
Do I have to map the media types and classes by myself e.g. with custom attributes?

```
[MimeType("application/document+json")]
class Mydocument
{
}
```

The "MediaTypeHeaderValue" class seems not to support such composed media types.
Is there a "best practice" for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7) allows for additional parameters to be defined for a media-type.

So this could be:

```
Content-Type: application/xml;.NET-Type=Customer
```

The convention of sub-subtype in the form of `<type>/<sub-subtype>+<subtype>` (`+` separated) is not canonical AFAIK, and just a convention.

In any case, you need to a bit work on both ends to implement media type composition coherency. But having multiple content-type is just wrong according to the spec.